# Libre office impress is slow to convert pptx to pdf

Tags: linux, command-line, libreoffice

I'm running Libre Office on my server to convert the powerpoint to a pdf file.

Using a .ppt file:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.ppt
```

is running fine and take like 3 or 4 seconds. But with a .pptx file

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.pptx
```

it takes like 3 minutes to execute. I have a decent server with

4 x 2.4ghz Intel

8 Gb RAM

Using this conversion on my desktop version of Libre Office it takes around 5 seconds too. Seems that the command line is slower than the GUI version. Anyone know what's could be causing this ?

Comment: Have you tried more than one PPTX?  Like is it slow with *all* PPTX's, or just specific one(s)?

Comment: Specific ones that are like 50 slides with charts and graphics. Over 2Mb in file size.

Comment: I wonder if this has been resolved. I suspect it's just the `{doc,xls,ppt}x` filters that are slow, as when I save a `pptx` file all my instances of LibreOffice turn grey for a few minutes, even the Calc one which has just a CSV file open.